# CVS :: Could not resolve hostname. How can I set the http proxy for CVS?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I'm using bsd unix.

I've issued `cvs -d anoncvs@anoncvs.netbsd.org:/cvsroot co pkgsrc` command.

It says:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname
>   anoncvs.netbsd.org: hostname nor
>   servname provided or not known
>
> cvs [checkout aborted] : end of file
>   from server (consult above messages if
>   any)

I'm behind proxy server. I did set the environment variable `http_proxy`. Do I need to configure cvs seperately? If so how? I couldn't find any of its configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTTP proxy supports "CONNECT" to port 22, then you might be able to use a suitable ProxyCommand in .ssh/config. I can't think of any command-line tools that'll do this off the top of my head.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow, your DNS isn't looking up anoncvs.netbsd.org.

Comment: Not enough information.  Figure out why you can't get to a DNS server.  Do you have DNS configured correctly on your client?  Are you able to look up the server from the command line?  Are you able to look up other sites?